# meta viewport tag doesn't seem to work in iOS UIWebView

Tags: ios, css, uiwebview, viewport, meta

Why isn't the following working? The intent is for the `div` to have 1/2 the width of the iphone screen. It works as expected in desktop browsers (e.g. OSX Safari and Chrome).

**index.html:**

```
<html>
<head>        
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />  
</head>
<body>
<br><br><br> 
    <div style="background-color: red; width: 50%">hello iphone</div>
</body></html>
```

**iOS code:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"index" withExtension:@"html"];
    [_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];   
}
```

**iphone simulator:**

[image: iphone 4s simulator]

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are `meta viewport` [bugs](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13510) in xcode 7.0.1 + iOS9; however, the workarounds suggested such as `initial-scale=1.0001` and `shrink-to-fit=no` have not worked for me. I've tried with the simulator and a physical device.

This is the only solution that has worked so far:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <br><br><br>
        <div id="red-div" style="background-color: red;">hello iphone</div>

        <script>
            document.getElementById('red-div').style.width = screen.width/2 + 'px';
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```